# How to display accents inside verbatim command

Tags: verbatim, accents

I have the following piece of code:

```
\newenvironment{mylisting}   
{\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{1em}}\item\scriptsize\bfseries}   
{\end{list}}   

\newenvironment{mytinylisting}   
{\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{1em}}\item\tiny\bfseries}   
{\end{list}}  

\begin{mylisting}   
\begin{verbatim}    
    I want to display an accent in this text (i.e. más)    
\end{verbatim}   
\end{mylisting}
```

The word "más" should be displayed with accent but I got:
m'as

The `verbatim` environment is ignoring the accent.

BTW According to my config, the accent is displayed just using ' before the letter.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please add a suitable preamble, in order to make the example compilable.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [`alltt` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alltt) -- it provides environment `alltt` that is supposed to behave exactly like verbatim, but it escapes all `<backslash>` and `{...}`. That way, you could surely write `\'{a}` to get the symbol, since `alltt` will expand the command `\'`.

Answer (score 5):

The semantics of the `verbatim` environment is that it displays your input verbatim (i.e., without any processing). So even if you have a setup, for example babel, where it is possible to enter accents using abbreviations such as `'a` such shortcuts are disabled within `verbatim`.

Thus, if you do require input processing and you only selected `verbatim` to get a typewriter font, then the obvious solution is to simply choose such a font directly in your definition, e.g., via `{\ttfamily ...}` or `\texttt{...}`. If on the other hand you are looking for some environment that obeys spacing `alltt` may help. It might be that shortcuts do not work but normal commands are executed so `\'a` will generate the correct glyph.

Answer (score 3):

If one loads the package `inputenc` with the proper option for the encoding of the file, then `verbatim` text will be printed correctly even with accented letters

If the file is UTF-8 encoded, then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % recommended for languages with accents
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
más mañana
\end{verbatim}
```

will be printed correctly. Of course the input encoding depends on the operating system, but mostly on the editor settings. Check yours: you might need `latin1` instead of `utf8`.