# How to write č,ć,ž,š,đ in verbatim?

Tags: verbatim

I have a problem with `verbatim`, it can't read my Serbian language symbols like č, ć, ž, š, đ.

If I try

```
\begin{verbatim}
č,ć,ž,š,đ 
\end{verbatim}
```

I get blank space, also if I try with `\v{c},\'{c},\v{z},\v{s},\dj{}` (this code is for normal text of č, ć, ž, š, đ in TeX) in `verbatim`, I get

```
\v{c},\'{c},\v{z},\v{s},\dj{}
```

instead  of

```
č,ć,ž,š,đ.
```

I use Overleaf , and after answer i get here i update my usepackage

```
    \documentclass[12pt,leqno, style=sailor,
    display=slides,
    paper=smartboard,
    orient=landscape]{article}



\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{code}{%
\lstset{frame=single,escapeinside=`',
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize \ttfamily}
}{}




%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{odj}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdflatex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}


\setlength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.3cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.7cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17.5cm}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLOR DEFINITION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{GreenYellow}   {cmyk}{0.15,0,0.69,0}
\definecolor{Yellow}        {cmyk}{0,0,1,0}
\definecolor{Goldenrod}     {cmyk}{0,0.10,0.84,0}
\definecolor{Dandelion}     {cmyk}{0,0.29,0.84,0}
\definecolor{Apricot}       {cmyk}{0,0.32,0.52,0}
\definecolor{Pea\v{c}}         {cmyk}{0,0.50,0.70,0}
\definecolor{Melon}         {cmyk}{0,0.46,0.50,0}
\definecolor{YellowOrange}  {cmyk}{0,0.42,1,0}
\definecolor{Orange}        {cmyk}{0,0.61,0.87,0}
\definecolor{BurntOrange}   {cmyk}{0,0.51,1,0}
\definecolor{Bittersweet}   {cmyk}{0,0.75,1,0.24}
\definecolor{RedOrange}     {cmyk}{0,0.77,0.87,0}
\definecolor{Mahogany}      {cmyk}{0,0.85,0.87,0.35}
\definecolor{Maroon}        {cmyk}{0,0.87,0.68,0.32}
\definecolor{BrickRed}      {cmyk}{0,0.89,0.94,0.28}
\definecolor{Red}           {cmyk}{0,1,1,0}
\definecolor{OrangeRed}     {cmyk}{0,1,0.50,0}
\definecolor{RubineRed}     {cmyk}{0,1,0.13,0}
\definecolor{WildStrawberry}{cmyk}{0,0.96,0.39,0}
\definecolor{Salmon}        {cmyk}{0,0.53,0.38,0}
\definecolor{CarnationPink} {cmyk}{0,0.63,0,0}
\definecolor{Magenta}       {cmyk}{0,1,0,0}
\definecolor{VioletRed}     {cmyk}{0,0.81,0,0}
\definecolor{Rhodamine}     {cmyk}{0,0.82,0,0}
\definecolor{Mulberry}      {cmyk}{0.34,0.90,0,0.02}
\definecolor{RedViolet}     {cmyk}{0.07,0.90,0,0.34}
\definecolor{Fu\v{c}sia}       {cmyk}{0.47,0.91,0,0.08}
\definecolor{Lavender}      {cmyk}{0,0.48,0,0}
\definecolor{Thistle}       {cmyk}{0.12,0.59,0,0}
\definecolor{Or\v{c}id}        {cmyk}{0.32,0.64,0,0}
\definecolor{DarkOr\v{c}id}    {cmyk}{0.40,0.80,0.20,0}
\definecolor{Purple}        {cmyk}{0.45,0.86,0,0}
\definecolor{Plum}          {cmyk}{0.50,1,0,0}
\definecolor{Violet}        {cmyk}{0.79,0.88,0,0}
\definecolor{RoyalPurple}   {cmyk}{0.75,0.90,0,0}
\definecolor{BlueViolet}    {cmyk}{0.86,0.91,0,0.04}
\definecolor{Periwinkle}    {cmyk}{0.57,0.55,0,0}
\definecolor{CadetBlue}     {cmyk}{0.62,0.57,0.23,0}
\definecolor{CornflowerBlue}{cmyk}{0.65,0.13,0,0}
\definecolor{MidnightBlue}  {cmyk}{0.98,0.13,0,0.43}
\definecolor{NavyBlue}      {cmyk}{0.94,0.54,0,0}
\definecolor{RoyalBlue}     {cmyk}{1,0.50,0,0}

\definecolor{Blue}          {cmyk}{1,1,0,0}
\definecolor{Cerulean}      {cmyk}{0.94,0.11,0,0}
\definecolor{Cyan}          {cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
\definecolor{ProcessBlue}   {cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\definecolor{SkyBlue}       {cmyk}{0.62,0,0.12,0}
\definecolor{Turquoise}     {cmyk}{0.85,0,0.20,0}
\definecolor{TealBlue}      {cmyk}{0.86,0,0.34,0.02}
\definecolor{Aquamarine}    {cmyk}{0.82,0,0.30,0}
\definecolor{BlueGreen}     {cmyk}{0.85,0,0.33,0}
\definecolor{Emerald}       {cmyk}{1,0,0.50,0}
\definecolor{JungleGreen}   {cmyk}{0.99,0,0.52,0}
\definecolor{SeaGreen}      {cmyk}{0.69,0,0.50,0}
\definecolor{Green}         {cmyk}{1,0,1,0}
\definecolor{ForestGreen}   {cmyk}{0.91,0,0.88,0.12}
\definecolor{PineGreen}     {cmyk}{0.92,0,0.59,0.25}
\definecolor{LimeGreen}     {cmyk}{0.50,0,1,0}
\definecolor{YellowGreen}   {cmyk}{0.44,0,0.74,0}
\definecolor{SpringGreen}   {cmyk}{0.26,0,0.76,0}
\definecolor{OliveGreen}    {cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}
\definecolor{RawSienna}     {cmyk}{0,0.72,1,0.45}
\definecolor{Sepia}         {cmyk}{0,0.83,1,0.70}
\definecolor{Brown}         {cmyk}{0,0.81,1,0.60}
\definecolor{Tan}           {cmyk}{0.14,0.42,0.56,0}
\definecolor{Gray}          {cmyk}{0,0,0,0.50}
\definecolor{Black}         {cmyk}{0,0,0,1}
\definecolor{White}         {cmyk}{0,0,0,0}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\dj{d\kern-0.4em\\v{c}ar"16\kern-0.1em}
\def\Dj{\mbox{\raise0.3ex\hbox{-}\kern-0.4em D}}

\def\o{\omega}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\F{{\cal F}}
\def\f{\frac}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\vf{\varphi}
\def\vfp{\varphi^\prime}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\L{{\bf L}}
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\b{\beta}
\def\ol{\overline}
\def\R{{\Bbb R}}\def\G{{\Bbb G}}\def\D{{\Bbb D}}
\def\C{{\Bbb C}}
\def\nin{\noindent}
\def\DJ{{\rm DJ\ }}

\newcommand{\tg}{\mathop{\rm tg}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\ctg}{\mathop{\rm ctg}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\arctg}{\mathop{\rm arctg}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\arcctg}{\mathop{\rm arcctg}\nolimits}


\def\df{\displaystyle\frac}
\def\dsum{\displaystyle\sum}
\def\dint{\displaystyle\int}
\def\fstp{{\hskip-0.5em}{\bf .}{\hskip0.5em}}

%\renewcommand{\figurename}{Slika}%
\newtheorem{te}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{de}{Definicija}
\newtheorem{po}{Posledica}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{stav}{Stav}
\newtheorem{primer}{Primer}

\def\bt{\color{Maroon}\begin{te}}
\def\et{\end{te}}

\def\bd{\color{Blue}\begin{de}}
\def\ed{\end{de}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Č \v{C} %
% Đ \Dj{} %
% Š \v{S} %
% Ž \v{Z} %

% č \v{c} %
% ć \'{c} %
% đ \dj{} %
% š \v{s} %
% ž \v{z} %
```

With that packages i get blank on

```
   \begin{verbatim}
č,ć,ž,š,đ 
\end{verbatim}
```

When i add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     % default is 'OT1'
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % needed if you have an older TeX distribution
\usepackage{lmodern}         % recommended
\setlength\parindent{0pt}    % just for this example
```

I get "ÄŊÄĞÅ”ÅąÄŚ" .

Comment: What happens when you write `{\ttfamily č,ć,ž,š,đ}`? You'll probably get the same blank space, correct?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please complete the question with a short full document showing the issue?

Comment: with `utf8` coding they should appear  as ć č š ž đ (depends on used fonts) ...

Comment: Please consider looking at this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44315/85946).

Comment: @Милош Вучковић Your file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Ye , i remove % at UTF-8 and its work now ! 
Is there optino also fore \begin{code}
                                        šđčćž
                                       \end{code}

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're using pdfLaTEx to compile your document. If that's the case, then as long as your TeX distribution is up to date, all you need to do is (a) load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1` (the default that needs to be overridden is `OT1`) and (b) load a font package such as `lmodern` that's optimized for accented glyphs. If you have an older TeX distribution (i.e., more than about 1 year old), you'll also need to (c) load the `inputenc` package with a suitable option; in all likelihood, the `utf8` option will be fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     % default is 'OT1'
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % needed if you have an older TeX distribution
\usepackage{lmodern}         % recommended
\setlength\parindent{0pt}    % just for this example

\begin{document}
č ć ž š đ

\textsf{č ć ž š đ}

\texttt{č ć ž š đ}

\begin{verbatim}
č,ć,ž,š,đ 
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document, all you need to do is load the `fontspec` package. (If you load `fontspec`, be sure *not* to load either `fontenc` or `inputenc`.) If the `fontspec` package is loaded, the default font family is "Latin Modern".

Comment: I use overleaf.

This is what i get when i use  that package "ÄŊÄĞÅ”ÅąÄŚ" , instead of  "č ć ž š đ"

Comment: Also in other text if i use standard package i cant write č ć ž š đ
 and will get in compile č ć ž š đ
, but with my package atm which i use i must \v{c} , \'{c} , \v{z}. \v{s} ,\dj{} to get č ć ž š đ.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,leqno, style=sailor,
    display=slides,
    paper=smartboard,
    orient=landscape]{article}



\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{code}{%
\lstset{frame=single,escapeinside=`',
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize \ttfamily}
}{}

\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 


\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

Comment: %\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{odj}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdflatex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}

this is all mypackage which i use

Comment: @МилошВучковић - Please edit your original posting. That'll make it much easier to see what's going on than trying to decipher stuff in a comment.

Comment: Ok, it edited .